# Gnuplot how to lower the number of tics in x axis

Tags: gnuplot, axis

The figure has too many xtics and ytics. Can I have half of them?

I know I can manually set tics in a way similar to this:

```
set xtics (1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024)
```

But I feel it is not a general solution. You can not manually set tics for all figures. I have loads of them and the gnuplot code is automatically generated using Java.

Here is the code for the figure: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45318932/gnuplot2.plt

Can you help lower down the number of x and y tics?

[image]

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Can you post the code on pastebin for example?

Comment: @Changwang Zhang Why wouldn't you post your code on here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no option in gnuplot to explicitly set the number of tics you want on an axis and have gnuplot decide where to put them.  (I really wish there were.)

One option you have is to use the `stats` command (in gnuplot 4.6+) to find out the range of the data:

```
ntics = 4

stats 'data.dat' using 1 name 'x' nooutput
stats 'data.dat' using 2 name 'y' nooutput
stats 'data.dat' using 3 name 'z' nooutput

set xtics x_max/ntics
set ytics y_max/ntics
set ztics z_max/ntics
```

You might have to adjust whether you want the tics to be at integer values or not, but that is the general idea.

Answer (score 18):

There are different ways to set the number of tics depending on what exactly you want to do. For a fixed segment of length 2, starting at zero and ending at 32:

```
set xrange [0:32]
set xtics 0,2,32
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

If you want an exponential increment, try the following

```
set xrange [0:32]
set for [i=0:5] xtics (0,2**i)
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

Or you can use a logarithmic scale (in base 2 in this case):

```
set xrange [1:32]
set logscale x 2
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to set how many tics to appear on x axis and let Gnuplot to find the exact tic value itself. I will plot using different data, so, you can not know the maximum/minimum x and y value unless you check it one by one from the datafile. This is hardly practical for me as I have thousands of data files and will generate more.

Comment: @Leo: Sorry, this did not come across to me when I read your question. Then I would recommend some variant of the approach suggested by @andyras, you check the ranges with the `stats` command and then set the tics depending on how many tics you want.

Comment: @Leo You could again file a feature-request :) The problem with the `stats` approach could be, that it will most probably generate awful tic steps. Gnuplot usually takes the tic position into account for auto scaling, so simulating it properly would include rounding the stats results properly.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks. Your answer helps me learn bits of gnuplot as well.

Comment: I agree with @Christoph that my method usually results in funny tic positions if the axis range is not nicely divisible by the number of tics I want.  I filed a feature request, since this is something I have wanted to have for a long time (https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/387/).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use for example

```
 set xtic 10
```

and it will display the tics on x-axis each 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I wanted to handle a little more generically in case the data changes while still using somewhat round looking numbers.  Therefore I made  a helper function:

```
endsinone(n) = strstrt(gprintf("%g", incrguess), "1")
getincr(range, maxincr, guess) = range/guess < maxincr ? guess : \
    (endsinone(guess) ? getincr(range, maxincr, 5*guess) : getincr(range, maxincr, 2*guess))
```

Then I just have to pass in the range for the axis, the most increments I want on it, and a very lower bound guess about what I would expect the smallest possible increment to be.  To keep the rounded looking numbers my functions assume the guess is expressible in the form `1eN` or `5eN` for some value `N`.  Ie (50 is good, so is 0.0000001, 505 is not).  With this function you just have to do something like

```
set xtics getincr(STATS_max, 6, 1e-9)
```

will return an `incr` of less than 6 tics, and there should be several of them assuming STATS_MAX > 1e-9.