# GNUPLOT: GPVAL_Y_MIN and GPVAL_Y_MAX in MULTIPLOT environment

Tags: plot, gnuplot, axis-labels

This being my first question here makes me a litte nervous. Here I go.

What I want to achieve is to plot four different data files in a multiplot (2x2, maybe more). So far I succesfully plotted this disregarding the different ranges in the y-axis on each, the x-axis is, however, homogenous to all subplots.

So, what I would like is to set to each y-axis 10 "ytics" with a number of minor tics (and, by extension, the x-axis as well). I believe this is done with GPVAL_X (or GPVAL_DATA_X) and GPVAL_Y (or GPVAL_DATA_Y) _MIN/_MAX. So far so good.

This however, does not achieve the result I was aiming for: http://postimg.org/image/uyavbtxn5/

On panel A) the y-axis is correctly divided in 10 segments, not so the x-axis.
Panel B) display correctly both axes.
Panel C) Display the x-axis correctly, whereas the y-axis no.
Panel D) Similar to C), but on the y-axis the tics appear disordered.

This poses the following questions:

1) How can I produce correctly this multiplot using GPVAL (or GPVAL_DATA)?

2) Why the plotted function appears in front of the corresponding label if it specified to otherwise?

This figure was produced with the following code:

```
reset
# Term
GNUTERM = "x11"
## Output
set t epslatex standalone color solid size 20in,12in font "ptm, 20"
set o "test.tex"
# Axes & Labels
set style line 11 lc rgb '#2F4F4F' lt 1
set border 3 back ls 11
set tics nomirror out
set format y "\\tiny $%2.2t \\cdot 10^{%S}$"
set format x "\\tiny $%1.1t$"
set xlabel "$\\rho$"
unset ylabel
unset key
# Grid
set style line 12 lc rgb'#2F4F4F' lt 0 lw 1.5
set grid back ls 12
# Border
set border 31 linewidth .75 # thin border
# Multiplot Files
set multiplot layout 2,2 columnsfirst
## UL
## Labels
LABEL = "A) $sin(x)$"
set obj 10 rect fill at graph 0.3, graph 0.75 size char strlen(LABEL), char 2
set label 10 at graph 0.3, graph 0.75 LABEL front center
plot sin(x)
## Tics
set xtics add GPVAL_X_MIN,(GPVAL_X_MAX-GPVAL_X_MIN)/10.,GPVAL_X_MAX
set ytics add GPVAL_Y_MIN,(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)/10.,GPVAL_Y_MAX
set mxtics 5
set mytics 5
## LL
## Labels
LABEL = "B) $cos(x)$"
set obj 10 rect fill at graph 0.3, graph 0.75 size char strlen(LABEL), char 2
set label 10 at graph 0.3, graph 0.75 LABEL front center
plot cos(x)
## Tics
set xtics add GPVAL_X_MIN,(GPVAL_X_MAX-GPVAL_X_MIN)/10.,GPVAL_X_MAX
set ytics add GPVAL_Y_MIN,(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)/10.,GPVAL_Y_MAX
set mxtics 5
set mytics 5
## UR
## Labels
LABEL = "C) $cos(x) sin(x)$"
set obj 10 rect fill at graph 0.3, graph 0.75 size char strlen(LABEL), char 2
set label 10 at graph 0.3, graph 0.75 LABEL front center
plot cos(x)*sin(x)
## Tics
set xtics add GPVAL_X_MIN,(GPVAL_X_MAX-GPVAL_X_MIN)/10.,GPVAL_X_MAX
set ytics add GPVAL_Y_MIN,(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)/10.,GPVAL_Y_MAX
set mxtics 5
set mytics 5
## LR
## Labels
LABEL = "D) $cos(x) / sin(x)$"
set obj 10 rect fill at graph 0.3, graph 0.75 size char strlen(LABEL), char 2
set label 10 at graph 0.3, graph 0.75 LABEL front center
plot cos(x)/sin(x)
## Tics
set xtics add GPVAL_X_MIN,(GPVAL_X_MAX-GPVAL_X_MIN)/10.,GPVAL_X_MAX
set ytics add GPVAL_Y_MIN,(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)/10.,GPVAL_Y_MAX
set mxtics 5
set mytics 5
unset multiplot
# Clean-up
set o
set t x11
reset
exit 0
```

Comment: I think you are getting something wrong: `GPVAL_X_MIN` is the minimum x-value of the *previous* plot, so its value will be available only *after* you plotted the function. Is it absolutely necessary, that you have exactly 10 tics on one axis. Usually you can use e.g. `set ytics 0.2` to set an increment of 0.2 between two y-tics.

Comment: Done, "stats" was the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Considering your solution, I'll vote to close your question as duplicate of [Gnuplot how to lower the number of tics in x axis](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23152207/2604213) (there are several other candidates).

Comment: Well no. It is not the same question. I've learned that the command "stats" it is indeed helpful. But the main idea behind this question is to understand how "multiplot" works with this, since each plot requires different tics (sometimes in both axes) for a multiplot command it is necesarry to ensure that for each a calling of "stats" is mandatory.